# Is "Mutual Authentication Protocol for HTTP" (RFC 8120) implemented in any browsers?

Tags: http, authentication, browser, http-headers

Does anybody know if any of the browsers have implemented the authentication Scheme "Mutual" [RFC 8120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8120)?

I was looking through the HTTP authentication type list at [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Authentication_schemes) but could not find any info online about there implementation status on either browsers or HTTP servers.

It is listed as "status: Experimental" but i do not know if that implies that it is implemented.

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

In an IETF RFC, status "experimental" refers to the fact that the spec itself is experimental; it is unrelated to whether there are implementations or not.

Regarding the actual question: no, I don't think any browser implements this.